# Drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: drivers

HI I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version. When I open bluetooth it says No adapter found. I own a HP Probook 445 G1. Can someone please give me a link for all the drivers?

rfkill list all output ,

0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
        Soft blocked : no 
        hard blocked : no

Comment: Can you add the output of `rfkill list all` to your question?

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked : no
     hard blocked : no